# how config php tidy extension?

Tags: php

how config tidy to get html content tidy? and without html tag and doctype
i want when i give tidy `"<p>ddddddd<lll>"` string it's return me `<p>dddddd</p>` not the html with doctype...
i used this config but what should i do for giving my desire result?

```
    $config = array(
       'indent'         => true,
       'output-xhtml'   => true,
       'wrap'           => 200);
        $tidy = new tidy;
        $tidy->parseString($output.". . .",$config,'utf8');
        $tidy->cleanRepair();
        return $tidy;
```

and is there any way to just set encoding without  send config parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use show-body-only

```
$config = array(
       'output-xhtml' => true,
       'show-body-only' => true,
       'wrap' => 0, 
          );
```